# Is there an SQL function that will allow me to input certain data in dependent on another column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

For example column 1 Start date and column 2 End date.
1/1/2020 | 3/31/2020
4/1/2020 | 6/30/2020
7/1/2020 | 10/31/2020

The column I am trying to get create that would be dependent on them would be Quarter.
So next to each one would be
Q1
Q2
Q3
etc...

So far my code looks like this

```
select
  user.p,
  user.e,
  concat(user.p,user.pr,user.r) AS Territories,
 parse_date(snapshot_date, '%d/%m/%y') AS Startdate,
 parse_date(refresh_date, '%d/%m/%y') AS EndDate,
 'Territory and Quota Program' Terrirtory_program
FROM 
  ods.simp.user
```

I originally had the parse date as date_format but google big query wouldn't recognize it as a function. When I run with parse date I get an error mismatch between format character '2' and string character '%'. Also note that every field in the user table is STRING type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user.p,
  user.e,
  CONCAT(user.p,user.pr,user.r) AS Territories,
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date) AS Startdate,
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', end_date) AS EndDate,
  'Q' || CAST(EXTRACT(Quarter FROM PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date)) AS STRING) AS Quarter,
  'Territory and Quota Program' Terrirtory_program
FROM `ods.simp.user`
```

So output (if to apply to sample data from your question) will be like below (skipping user's specific columns here)

```
Row Startdate   EndDate     Quarter Terrirtory_program   
1   2020-01-01  2020-03-31  Q1      Territory and Quota Program  
2   2020-04-01  2020-06-30  Q2      Territory and Quota Program  
3   2020-07-01  2020-10-31  Q3      Territory and Quota Program
```

To test, play with above - use below example with sample data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `ods.simp.user` AS (
  SELECT '1/1/2020' start_date, '3/31/2020' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT '4/1/2020', '6/30/2020' UNION ALL
  SELECT '7/1/2020', '10/31/2020' 
)
SELECT
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date) AS Startdate,
  PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', end_date) AS EndDate,
  'Q' || CAST(EXTRACT(Quarter FROM PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', start_date)) AS STRING) AS Quarter,
  'Territory and Quota Program' Terrirtory_program
FROM `ods.simp.user`
```

Comment: I changed the 'start_date to snapshot_date because it wasn't recognized, giving me errors.Snapshot date is one of the original tables that I am formating. I am still getting the previous error Mismatch between format character '2' and character '%'.

Comment: Your code was very helpful for sure! I am new to this and doing this for my job lol. It is actually still not working all the way yet. I am not sure why. I fix one error and get another . I have to rely on the web as I don't have anyone to help at work... Right now the error is saying Could not cast literal "%d/%m/%y" to type DATE at [12:62]. I added the new syntax provided. I am not getting errors from it. But it is not in my table that I am pulling data from. I was just using it as an example from the template that I need to create the table from and use the data from the fields.